# I am getting an exception when my tcp client connects to the server with ip address but works with "localhost"

Tags: c#, tcp, sockets

I am writing a simple C# tcp client and server program.  The server will eventually be on a different machine but now I am just testing on the same machine.  I am getting an exception error "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted" when I create my TcpClient using the ip address. But it works if I use "localhost" instead of ip address.  I get the ip address from ipconfig.  I also try having the server running on a different machine and my TcpClient gets the same exception when I specify the remote machine's ip address.  How do I make the connection using ip address?  thanks.

Below is the code where I create the TcpClient

```
            IPAddress ipaddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.128.100");
            int port = 3000;


            int tries = 0;
            client = null;
            while (tries < 6) // try for 3 seconds
            {
                try
                {
                    tries++;
                    IPEndPoint ipEndpt = new IPEndPoint(ipaddr, port);
                    client = new TcpClient(ipEndpt);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    client = null;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
```

Comment: also, post some code, it will help.

Comment: yes..thank you that was the problem.  I should call Connect and pass in the server IPEndPoint instead of passing to the TcpClient constructor

Comment: sorry, I just saw I commented instead of answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create tcp client, are you defining a port? if so, you should not. instead, you will connect to the port of the server.

Comment: Actually, you must specify a port when creating a `TcpClient`. However, what you must not do, is specify the port (for the `IPEndPoint` used to instantiate the `TcpClient`) to which you will be connecting to (when connecting to a service on the local host machine). So, if you want to make a Telnet connection on your own local machine, the `TcpClient` end point address should be any port other than 23. Then you connect to your local IP Address on port 23 to initiate the Telnet connection. But your answer pointed me in the right direction, so thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is probably another service listening on the interface on that port.

You should try

```
netstat -oan
```

and search for port 3000. If you found a line in the result the last file is the pid of the process which you can also find in the taskmanager.

```
TCP    192.168.128.100:3000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTEN         4711
```

4711 = PID